# function Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Does anyone knows how to prove that the function $f$ defined from $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $\sin(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}})$ if $x\ne 0$ and equal $0$ if $x=0$ is Riemann integrable? Thanks.

Comment: Just say it's bounded near 0 and continuous elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** If $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ and integrable on $[c,1]$ for every $0<c<1$, is $f$ integrable on $[0,1]$?